# Circuit Analysis with constant current and voltage sources

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, constant-current

This is a homework question of sorts. I am supposed to find the voltage across AB.

I know that the answer is 24 volts by traversing from B to D to C to A adding up voltages of resistors, but should I not be considering the contribution of other elements in the circuit, for example, the 10 V source? Pretty sure there's a gap in my knowledge.

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I know that the answer is 24 volts by traversing from B to D to C to A adding up voltages of resistors, but should I not be considering the contribution of other elements in the circuit, for example, the 10 V source?

Pretty sure there's a gap in my knowledge.

Comment: A current source is a device that (ideally) provides whatever voltage is necessary at its terminals to cause the specified current to flow. Does that help?

Comment: Nice. A different way to see ideal current sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I know that the answer is 24 volts by traversing from B to D to C to A
>   adding up voltages of resistors, but should I not be considering the
>   contribution of other elements in the circuit, for example, the 10 V
>   source?*

Yes it seems confusing but it isn't. If there's something uniquely in series with a current source then that "something" has no effect; the current source overrides its presence. So, you have 3 amps passing through the 8 ohm resistor and that produces a volt drop of 24 volts.

As previously stated, the 4 ohm in series with the 2 amp current source is irrelevant hence the voltage across the 10 ohm resistor is 20 volts and, this is cancelled by the opposing 20 volt source in the "B" line.

Hence, 24 volts is the final answer.

Comment: So, that means in any line containing a current source and any other component, the current source dominates?

Comment: And likewise, in parallel configuration, the voltage source(if it exists) will override any other characteristics present?

Comment: Current source dominates purely series components and voltage source dominates parallel components.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you for the answer.